# How to set default language in Sitecore multilingual solution?

Tags: sitecore, multilingual, sitecore7

I have a Sitecore website in 3 languages (en, es and fr) and user can change the language   with toggle switch on website.

In `web.config` sites section the `defaultLanguage` is "en", but even after this when I go to  spanish version like www.abc.com/es.aspx, then after if I go to www.abc.com (english version) the website still remains in Spanish language.

Any idea how to set the default language to english?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming that your `sites` config contains

```xml
<site ... language="en" ... />
```

you can define your own module that for every new session will reset language to the default one.

First you need to create module class:

```cs
using Sitecore.Globalization;
using System;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.SessionState;

namespace My.Assembly.Namespace
{
  public class ResetLanguageModule : IHttpModule, IRequiresSessionState
  {
    public void Init(HttpApplication app)
    {
      if (app.Modules["Session"] != null)
      {
        SessionStateModule session = (SessionStateModule) app.Modules["Session"];
        session.Start += Session_Start;
      }

      app.BeginRequest += Application_BeginRequest;
    }

    private static void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      // if there is no referrer or user comes from external site
      if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer == null
        || HttpContext.Current.Request.UrlReferrer.Host != HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host)
      {
        // if user is on the root
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl == "/")
        {
          ResetLanguage();
        }
      }
    }

    private static void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      ResetLanguage();
    }

    private static void ResetLanguage()
    {
      if (Sitecore.Context.Language.Name != Sitecore.Context.Site.Language)
      {
        Language currentSiteLanugage;
        if (Language.TryParse(Sitecore.Context.Site.Language, out currentSiteLanugage))
        {
          Sitecore.Context.SetLanguage(currentSiteLanugage, true);
        }
      }
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
    }
  }
}
```

and then register the module in `web.config`:

```xml
<system.webServer>
  <modules>
    ... all existing modules
    <add name="ResetLanguageModule" type="My.Assembly.Namespace.ResetLanguageModule, My.Assembly" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

This might not work when you have your browser open and you just close the tab and reopen, as the browser might still keep the session alive.

Comment: Thanks Maras, is there is a way to check that will work in the new tab also. For example whenever the url is www.abc.com without any language in it will go for English version of the website.

Comment: I updated my answer. Now when user comes from an external site or just type url in a new tab, language will be reset. If you want to reset the language every time user is on the site root (including clicking a link navigating to `www.abc.com`, just remove checking `UrlReferrer`. And there is no need for using `Session.Start` anymore with updated solution.

Answer (score 1):

In your `<site>` configuration, set the `language` attribute for your default. E.g.

```
<sites>
  <site name="mysite" language="es-ES" ... />
</sites>
```

Then to switch you can use the path like you showed, e.g `/en/foo` or `/es/foo` or you can even use a query string to switch languages, like so: `?sc_lang=en` or `?sc_lang=es-ES`

Refer to [this page](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Articles/Administration/Configuring%20Multiple%20Sites/Configuring%20Sites%20in%20web,-d-,config%20File.aspx) for more details.

Comment: I am also doing same. But, suppose i closed my website and i was on spanish version of site. If i am going to open the website next time without clearing cookies and cache, it goes to spanish version instead of english which is default language.

Comment: That's by design. You just said it yourself. The user switches to Spanish and therefore a cookie is set to to say "now use Spanish." Default doesn't mean ALWAYS, default means first time you come, it's set to English. Once the user sets Spanish they are cookied and that's how it stays.

Answer (score 0):

By default the languageresolver switches from language defined in the url to language stored in the cookie automatically. (called asNeeded in the config of the linkmanager)

Setting languageEmbedding="always" should solve your issue.

also: check this blog from John: http://www.sitecore.net/nederland/Community/Technical-Blogs/John-West-Sitecore-Blog/Posts/2010/11/Overriding-Sitecores-Logic-to-Determine-the-Context-Language.aspx